# Laravel Column not found - Issue with authentication

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

So I'm trying to set up authentication on Laravel. I went to create an account a laravel.app/auth/register and it worked. I saw the user in the database table.. I then deleted the user from the table and now when I open /auth/register/ I get:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'users.id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where `users`.`id` = 1 limit 1)

What was wrong about what I did and how can I fix it?

Any help appreciated. Cheers.

Comment: Instead of using `users.id`, use `id`

Comment: Can you manually check that you have an `id` column in your `users` table?

Comment: Therein lies the problem. At some point I changed id to cid.. I have no idea why :/

Answer (score 0):

Have you change the table accidentally? Remove the tables include migrations and migrate again. or

```
php artisan migrate:refresh
```